# Issue with variable scope in javascript/NodeJS

Tags: javascript, variables, node.js

Im having issues with accessing the value of a variable in NodeJS. Here is some example code and the results I get.

```
for (var z=0, zMessageCount = Description.length; z<zMessageCount; z++){
    console.log(z);
    if(SomeOtherColumnValue[z] > 9){
        client.query('SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE some_column=' + ColumnValue[z], function (err, results) {
            if(results < 1){
                console.log(z);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Here is the issue I am having. In for "for" loop the value of z is going from 0 to 14. However when I try to access it from the client.query function its value is 15. It is not adding 1 to itself for every loop. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: `z` should be fine in that scope. Hmm, wild guess but what does client.query actually do with the string you pass it? I have a feeling it sends it to another non-blocking callback function and it's being executed after your loop finishes, rather than write away. What library is this?

Comment: client.query is part of node-mysql. It does appear as if it is... Is there a different way I should be doing this?

Comment: Might be wrong, but you could try `var columnName = ColumnName[z];` and pass that into client.query. Defining `columnName` after your if statement. This might help from the z being passed as a reference into `client.query`

Comment: The anonymous function (the third param in client.query) creates a closure which allows it to see the value of 'z' as it continues to get incremented. +1 to generalhenry's solution below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap z in a function to provide scope.

```
for (var z=0, zMessageCount = Description.length; z<zMessageCount; z++){
    console.log(z);
    if(SomeOtherColumnValue[z] > 9){
      zQuery(z);  
    }
}

function zQuery (z) {
  client.query('SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE some_column=' + ColumnValue[z], function (err, results) {
      if(results < 1){
         console.log(z);
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much. I spent hours trying to figure out where I went wrong.